# Create dynamic rest api url in apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, dynamic

I have a requirement where I have 4 fields in which a user will fill phone numbers. On clicking save it will make a Rest API call. The 4 phone numbers have to go in an array in the URL as shown below.
I want to make this dynamic rather than hard-coding as string.string[0], string.string[1]... and so on.

```
ValidateNumberBatch.PhoneNumbers.string.string[0]=1234567890&ValidateNumberBatch.PhoneNumbers.string.string[1]=1234567891
```

Main URL -

```
 String endpoint = 'https://ws.castiron.com/Castiron/PhoneVal20/PhoneValidation20/ValidateNumberBatch?LicenseInfo.RegisteredUser.UserID=XXXXXXX&LicenseInfo.RegisteredUser.Password=XXXXXX&'+noOfPhonenumber;

String noOfPhonenumber = 'ValidateNumberBatch.PhoneNumbers.string.string[0]=1234567890&ValidateNumberBatch.PhoneNumbers.string.string[1]=1234567891&format=JSON';
```

Comment: Question - Why not go with POST API call instead of GET?

Comment: The question is not about GET or POST. The question is how can i make string.string[0] as dynamic...instead of hard-coding..

Comment: Let me rephrase it, why to pass parameters in url, this looks like the case where passing dynamic attribute in payload (body) of POST request would make more sense.

Comment: If you forcefully want to do dynamic things as url parameters may be you can form the request as https://domain?phoneData=<fieldName1>$<fieldValue1>,<fieldName2>$<fieldValue2>,<fieldName3>$<fieldValue3>
Now read phoneData split it via comma and then split individual items.
I would still consider rethinking why not go with POST as you might come up new configuration and bundling that up as in url parameters is not a good idea.

Comment: This was given like this only with GET not with POST...

Comment: Who is selecting the parameter names? Where are you getting the data from? It's hard to help you without a lot more context.

Comment: Build an apex array (list) of each phoneNumber and then use `String.join(theList,theDelimiter)` to make the code cleaner. The second argument to String.join need not be a single character